# How can I fix garbled multibyte text when using Text::vCard's as_string() method?

Tags: perl, utf-8, vcf-vcard

When using multibyte UTF-8 characters in a NOTE node, characters are garbled/lost around the newline.

For example:

```
$vcard = $address_book->add_vcard();
$vcard->version('3.0');
$vcard->FN('Tèśt Ûšér');
$vcard->NOTE('①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳');
say $vcard->as_string();
```

Produces:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Tèśt Ûšér
NOTE:①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪��
 �⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳①②③④
 ⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯�
 ��⑱⑲⑳①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧��
 �⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳①
 ②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬�
 ��⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳
END:VCARD
```

How would go about fixing this? I also posted this as [an issue on the text-vcard project page](https://github.com/ranguard/text-vcard/issues/37). I think this is related to how the new lines are inserted (by inserting the raw bytes: \x0D\x0A), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you `use utf8;` in your program?

Comment: @cjm in the github ticket that OP linked he has a full code example to reproduce the problem. It has `use utf8` there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the culprit is Text::vCard::Node->_wrap_utf8(). I was able to at least get it to stop cutting up characters by bypassing that method all together.

```
sub _wrap_utf8 {
my ( $self, $key, $value, $max, $newline ) = @_;

#bypass wrapping
return $key . $value;

…

}
```